# Configure all Devise controllers to use a different layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, devise, controller

I have a Rails app which application layout is used to render an AngularJS app.  However, I would like that all the Devise controllers use another layout. I don't need Angular in there.

How can I tell Devise to use a different layout for all its controllers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably should review this entry: [How To: Create custom layouts](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-custom-layouts).

More or less, you can set it via `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :layout_by_resource

  protected

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      "layout_name_for_devise"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```

Or via configuration (config/application.rb):

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.layout "devise"
  Devise::RegistrationsController.layout proc{ |controller| user_signed_in? ? "application" : "devise" }
  Devise::ConfirmationsController.layout "devise"
  Devise::UnlocksController.layout "devise"            
  Devise::PasswordsController.layout "devise"        
end
```